# SQL Server query to attach a MDF file without a LDF file but set the LDF path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to attach a `.MDF` database file via a SQL query that has no `.LDF` file. That said, I need the `.LDF` path to be able to be set to a different location from the `.MDF`.

As far as I can tell `CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH` doesn't provide this ability.

Any way around this?

Comment: Let it rebuild the transaction log, detach the database, move the transaction log file to where you want it, then attach again. This is the obvious, clumsy way, and probably also the only way -- in theory the LDF could be built in a location other than the default one for log files, but I understand why the engineers didn't really consider it a priority to expose this in the command. Attaching a DB without a log is not a default workflow (restoring from backup is, if you want to deal with single files).